# How to get the asosciated id from an NSDictionary in a JSON response

Tags: objective-c, json, api, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to parse a JSON response, and I want to know how I could get a value from an NSDictionary?

Basically, the iOS app uses `AFJSONRequestOperation` to retrieve a JSON response from `localhost:3000/api/csv_files` and puts the results from the request in a NSArray.

I'm using the below snippet to accomplish the above statement.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                            NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *) JSON;
                                                            // this is the array that stores the JSON response
                                                            NSArray *csvFiles = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"csv_files"];
                                                            [csvFiles enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj,NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                                                                NSString *csvFileFilename = [obj objectForKey:@"csv_file_filename"];
//                                                              NSLog(@"CSV Filenames:%@",csvFileFilename);
                                                                [weakSelf processJSONResponse:csvFiles];
                                                                                            }];


                                                    }   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                            NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
                                                                                            }];
    [operation start];
```

Now I am trying to process the JSON response, so that the UUID of the device matches the UUID stored in the filename of one of the uploaded files to the API.  And I accomplish this with the below snippet,

```
- (void)processJSONResponse:(NSArray *) csvFiles {

    NSLog(@"CSV Files array:%@",csvFiles);

    NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv];

    BOOL hasString = NO;
    for (NSDictionary *fileInfo in csvFiles) {
        if ([fileInfo[@"csv_file_filename"] isEqualToString:fileName]) {
            hasString = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%hhd",hasString);
}
```

Now after I find the accompanying file with the correct filename in the `csvFiles` NSArray, how could I find the associated id attribute?

The JSON response looks like this,
[image: JSON response]

Comment: Since you know how to process the JSON results and you know how to get the `csv_file_filename`, why don't you seem to know how to get the `csv_file_id` value? Is that your question? Please clarify what you really need help with.

Comment: @rmaddy I need help getting the `id` which in this case is `85` not the csv_file_id.  I am not sure how I can get the `id` after I have found the correct file based on filename.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks I'll try that out in a minute or two and get back with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)getIDFromCSVArray:(NSArray *) csvFiles {

    NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    for (NSDictionary *fileInfo in csvFiles) {
        if ([fileInfo[@"csv_file_filename"] containsString:idfv]) {
            return [[fileInfo[@"id"] integerValue];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you have one to many open brackets on this line `return [[fileInfo[@"id"] integerValue];`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSInteger)idOfCSVFile:(NSDictionary*)csvFileDict
{
    NSNumber* idNumber = [csvFileDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    if (idNumber) return [idNumber integerValue];
    return -1; // I guess it should not happen...
}
```